# How to give IIS AppPool Desktop Rights

Tags: c#, security, iis-7.5

The action I need help about, is to execute a EXE file on own servers disk from a intranet-webpage, which IIS are on same server-installation. The webpage use a business layer to execute a ProcessStart together with given parameters.

When I perform the execution from web, the taskmanager show me that the application are starting up with the IIS AppPool of webpage as user. Few seconds later it's killed. In my database logs, I can see;

`The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '\\computer\pathfile.ext'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.`

That's correct. The EXE tool are, in turn, loading files from other computers. This is a special behavior which are well studied and well working while using the tool from desktop.

**My goal/question,**
I want this web-function-call behave with desktop rights. Is it possible at all?

The IIS AppPool have a regular setup with account ApplicationPoolIdentity. I appeared to be "lucky unwise", without knowledge about how much IIS 7.5 and Windows Server 2008 R2 raised the security model since <=IIS6.

I tried to change the app-pool user to NetworkService, Administrator.
I tried to set the application with app-pool as exec/read right
I even tried to let webapp to run a batch-file with a call to application inside..

> Then I was begin to change the ProcessStart-behavior. And here, I
>   don't know much of what to do. I tried to add VERB runas. Force a
>   password prompt is not a solution here. I tried to simulate a
>   username/password. No luck there. I also tried to add runas /user:
>   blabla as parameters with ProcessStart, after used /savecred in a
>   desktop command window once. No luck there.

Maybe this should work but I just don't understand the correct setup of properties. I add the ProcessStart code snippet below, also added some commented code to let you see what I tried.

```
 public string RunProcess(ApplicationType type, int param)
    {
        currentSelection = GetApplicationType(type);

        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(currentSelection.Path);

        info.CreateNoWindow = false;
        info.UseShellExecute = true;
        //info.UseShellExecute = false;
        //info.ErrorDialog = false;
        //info.UserName = "dummyUsEr";
        //info.Password = this.SecurePwd("DummyPWd");

        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        info.Arguments = string.Format(" {0}", param.ToString());

        using (Process exec = Process.Start(info))
        {
            try
            {
                exec.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch 
            {  
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
```

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, and perhaps help some another guy/girl browsing to this question, I attach the snippet of Password-generation,

```
protected System.Security.SecureString SecurePwd(string pwd)
{
    SecureString securePwd = new SecureString();

    foreach (char ch in pwd.ToCharArray())
        securePwd.AppendChar(ch);

    return securePwd;
}
```

Comment: If you run the IIS as an administrator of your server, you can run process from web app, but the error message suggests that the '\\computer\pathfile.ext' is locked by another process and this can cause the failure of your process.

Comment: @Max, Thanks. Though, you forgot to type the other part that says 'or you need permission to view its data'. I will also repeat - this is a well studied and well established desktop application. If I don't missunderstand you about IIS rights, there are no realistic idea to run the whole IIS as administrator. There are other webapplications and other application pools on this computer.

Comment: Just to prove the scenario I just deployed a simple WPF GUI which inherit the identical business logic. Added a few button and run from the Console. Tada. How nice if this rights could be served from IIS Isolations..

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've tried putting in a specific username and password for the process start impersonation, but you say that the process accesses files on another computer and I don't see any mention of specifying a domain name which presumably you would need to access remote files?
So like this:

```
info.Domain = "domainname";
info.UserName = "dummyUsEr";
info.Password = "DummyPWd";
```

Also, what does this.SecurePwd() do and have you tried it with just the straight password string that you're passing into it?

Comment: Thank's. That's correct. I'm not sure about how to use the domain, because there are no specific domain of those computers. They are stand alone windows machine that only shares the C network (192.168.2.xx). Some are Windows XP, Windows 7 and such. the `this.SecurePwd()` is just a translator because the method require a specific conversion of a chararray. The password is however not the problem (?) because the application would not start at all if so.

Comment: Please read a little about what ProcessStartInfo does and works, because you simply can't attach a string into Password.

Comment: So does the user you've specified definitely have access to the specific folder/file mentioned in the error message? If you try to access that file manually are you prompted for login details?

Comment: That's correct. That user have the right to run the application from desktop and access the files with success. Well tested, documented and used.

Comment: Is mapping the folders as drives an option, even just to test it and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: I think the approach here lies in how the IIS-invoked user rights are  inherited to resources outside the IIS Isolation? I.e. if the user have admin access in desktop, it does not help if it was first invoked from a account which has partial or no right. At least would I build a security model myself, like that. But I can have wrong, it happens before :-)

Comment: Though, I understand your approach. It can, in fact, act a work-around.

Comment: All access from a .NET application in IIS runs under the user account specified in the application pool, unless impersonation is in use.
To set up an application pool to run under a different user you should first modify the account you want to use by adding the user to the IIS_IUSRS group.
This may be enough, but you may also need to edit the Local Security Policies to give the account permission to log on as a service.
Then create a new application pool with that user set as the identity in the advanced settings. 
This may still not be enough, you'll need correct folder permissions too.